# css class not applying styling, but id is applying styling?

Tags: html, css, styling

I have my HTML set up as follows

```
<div>
    <ul>
        <li></li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a class="nodecoration"></a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.nodecoration {
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

When I change my anchor tag to `<a id="nodecoration"></a>` and change the CSS to:

```
#nodecoration {
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

The element now styles. Why is this?

Side note: I am also using Twitter Bootstrap, is the CSS from that interfering?

Comment: Nothing glaring. This likely has to do with *specificity* and other styles you have not provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an indication that another style rule has precedence over that rule. You may want to make that rule more specific by using `a.nodecoration` which should increase its precedence.

FYI, tools like firebug for Firefox will tell you which rule(s) have the higher precedence.

Comment: even after changing the css to a.nodecoration it still didnt work. how can i make it more specific? using firebug to inspect the element, i can see that the css is crossed out. edit: i fixed it, by doing li a.nodecration

Comment: Try adding `!important` to the rule. Also, use firebug or Chrome's developer tools to see which rule is over-riding your rule. That will tell you exactly what you need to do to solve this.

Comment: thanks. not sure if you saw that i edited my previous comment, i fixed it by doing li a.nodecoration

Answer (score 1):

bootstrap already have rule for a, you need to be more specific.

- tag 1 point
- class 10 points
- id 100 point

you may count in this way to know which one is more specific.